# K&R C chapter 2 assignment operators and expressions

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, assignment-operator, twos-complement

Assignment operators are not something I expected to struggle with. Everything in this section so far is familiar, but the way they explain it makes it seem foreign. I think it's the bitwise operators I'm confused about.

Anyway here is the part I don't get.

> The function `bitcount` counts the number of 1-bits in its integer argument.
>
> ```
> /*bitcount: count 1 bits in x */
> int bitcount (unsigned x)
>
> {
>   int b;
>
>   for(b=0; x != 0; x >>= 1) {
>     if(x & 01) 
>       b++;
>   return b;
> }
> ```
>
> Declaring the argument `x` to be unsigned ensures that when it is right-shifted, vacated bits will be filled with zeros, not sign bits, regardless of the machine the program is run on.

Not that I really understand the code, but this last sentence is confusing me the most. What does this mean? Does it mean "ones" by "sign bits" and does this have to do with twos complement?

I really had trouble getting through the bitwise operations. Can anyone recommend some comprehensive material to supplement the bitwise stuff in this book?

Comment: I suggest running the code through a debugger with different values for `x` ("negative" and positive values). Then do the same but use `int x` instead.

Comment: Spend a few minutes reviewing [bit shifting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm) with real values to see the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `x` is two’s complement. For illustration, let‘s use an eight-bit width. (C always shifts in a wider width, at least that of `int`.)

If `x` is 64 (01000000<sub>2</sub>) and we shift it right one bit, we get 32  (00100000<sub>2</sub>). When we repeat that, we get 16 (00010000<sub>2</sub>), 8 (00001000<sub>2</sub>), 4 (00000100<sub>2</sub>), 2 (00000010<sub>2</sub>) , and 1 (00000001<sub>2</sub>).

When `x` is −64, two’s complement represents it with 11000000<sub>2</sub>. If we shift that right and bring in a 0 bit, the bits are 01100000<sub>2</sub>, which represents 64+32 = 96. So −64 becomes 96. Now, that might be fine if one were just working with bits. But, if we want to use bit-shifting to divide numbers, we want −32, not 96. The bits for −32 are 11100000<sub>2</sub>. So we can get that by bring in a 1 bit instead of a 0 bit. And the bits for −16 are 11110000<sub>2</sub>. Then −8, −4, −2, and −1 are 11111000<sub>2</sub>, 11111100<sub>2</sub>, 11111110<sub>2</sub>, 11111111<sub>2</sub>. In each case, we bring in a 1 bit when shifting.

So, if we want to use bit-shifting for division, there is a simple rule for a one-bit shift: Shift all bits right one spot and leave the sign bit as is (0 or 1). If we are shifting more than one bit, keep copying the sign bit.

That is called an arithmetic right shift. So, we have two kinds of right shift: An arithmetic right shift that copies the sign bit, and a logical right shift that brings in 0 bits.

For unsigned types, the C standard says a right shift is logical.

For signed types, the C standard does not say whether it is arithmetic or logical. It leaves it to the implementation to define which that implementation uses (or possibly to define something else). That might be due to the history; early machines might not have provided arithmetic right-shift instructions (and may not even have used two’s complement), although it seems hard to imagine these days.

So, when you are writing code that shifts right and you want to be sure of the result you will get, you can use an unsigned type to be sure to get a logical shift.

Answer (score 1):

In twos complement representation the highest order bit is reserved for the sign. The highest order bit is 0 for positive numbers and 1 for negative numbers.
If you right shift the bits of a negative number the 1 originally in the highest order bit will be shifted to the next lower order bit, eventually ending up in the lowest order bit if you keep shifting the bits.
In the code the for loop shifts the bits of x by one bit position and assigns the shifted value to x.

```
for (b = 0; x != 0; x >>=1 )
```

First b, which is used to count the number of 1 bits in the number is set to 0.

The condition to continue the loop is x != 0. When all the 1 bits are shifted out of x the only thing left will be 0 bits. x will then equal 0.

The operation performed after each iteration is to right-shift the value in x by 1.

The if condition in the body of the loop performs bit-wise AND operation on x. The bit mask has a value of 1, which is an instance of the int value with all bits 0 except the lowest order bit. That AND operation will evaluate to 1 (or true in C) if the lowest order bit is 1, and to 0 (or false in C) if the lowest order bit is 0. The count of one bits is incremented if the if condition is true.

Comment: Re “If you right shift the bits of a negative number…”: C 2018 6.5.7 5 makes the right-shift of a negative number implementation-defined.

Comment: It is implementation-defined because C does not specify the hardware representation of signed numbers. Ones complement does not use a sign bit, but has both -0 and +0 values. Twos complement, the most commonly used representation, uses a sign bit.

Comment: Sure, that may be the reason right shift is implementation-defined. Nonetheless, it is implementation-defined, so it cannot be asserted unconditionally that a right shift acts thusly.

Comment: @JimRogers, I think you could say the top bit is a sign bit also in ones' complement? It's one for negative values (incl. -0), and zero for positive values (incl. +0). Actually, wouldn't shifting right and copying the sign bit work for ones' complement too, up to rounding? Take -5 in four bits, it's `1 010`, shifted right gives `1 101` or -2, shifted right is `1 110`, or -1. Actually it looks to work better than in two's complement in that it's symmetric around zero, so that `((-b) >> 1) == -(b >> 1)`. That said, I didn't stop to think about this for too long, so just tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JimRogers I'm no expert on bitwise operations but I think it just coincidentally works for those numbers. -6 is 1001 but -3 is 1100.

Comment: @ilkkachu While it is true that the high order bit for ones complement is 0 that bit does not act as a sign bit. It is simply the complement of the corresponding positive value. In twos complement the high order bit does not indicate a power of 2. Instead it is merely a sign bit.

Comment: @JimRogers, so, what in practice is the difference between a sign bit and a bit that only just so happens to indicate the sign? In two's complement, the high bit can be taken to indicate a negative power of two (e.g. -2^7 in an 8-bit number), so really it just that the bit position has an exceptional weight. In neither of ones' complement or two's complement is it possible to just flip the high bit without other changes to get the negative of a number, so in that sense, neither has a pure sign bit. Sign-magnitude formats do.

Comment: @ilkkachu The difference occurs when right-shifting bits as in the example attempted in the original question. The count of 1-bits will be correct for a negative ones-complement number but incorrect for a twos-complement number because the final bit counted will be the sign bit, which is not one of the numeric bits in the value.